# Is it possible for a person or object to spontaneously vanish into thin air?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have read many stories/reports of people seeing people, cars, or random objects vanish into thin air right in front of them. (Namely, the glitch in the matrix subreddit on Reddit.)

Is this possible?

Comment: There are a million different ways this question could be interpreted, the conclusions will depends on what you mean by "vanish". In general, the answer is no, things cannot simply cease to exist by any observed mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

To vanish into thin air, all the cells and molecules of the body need to be dispersed, so one needs to break the bonding forces between them. This requires a huge amount of energy. Without that supply of energy, what people have probably witnessed is an illusion, an optical effect or maybe a hallucination.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to this, the first negative and the second positive:

1. Generally this idea comes from the idea of the object slipping into a different dimension.  It has been shown with some certainty that there is no other dimension on the macro scale.  You can easily test this by lighting a normal light bulb.  If you were to measure the total power input and the total power output (light and heat) you would see that both are equal.  If there was another macro dimension then some of the light or heat would slip into that other dimension and not be measurable in our dimensions. (Scientists are still considering whether other dimensions exist on the micro scale, i.e. on the order of 1/1,000,000th the size of a proton.)
2. There is a newly patented technology that can make you seem to disappear into thin air.  (Note that I know the people who own this company)  [Hyperstealth](https://www.hyperstealth.net/) has developed a sheet of plastic that refracts the light so that an object, a person or even a tank, seems to disappear into thin air at all wavelengths.  If you remember the old 3D pictures that changed the image when you walk past, this plastic is nothing more than a sheet of that with no picture behind it.  So all things are possible with some imagination.